# FreeBSD portsnap fetch fails

Tags: freebsd, freebsd-ports

This seems like a really straightforward problem, but I haven't had much luck looking around the internet so far. (A couple message boards are talking about it, but they don't offer any solutions.)

### The Problem

When I run `sudo portsnap fetch`, I get:

```
Looking up portsnap.FreeBSD.org mirrors... none found.
Fetching snapshot tag from portsnap.FreeBSD.org... failed.
No mirrors remaining, giving up.
```

### Details

- The internet connection appears to be working.
- I've successfully used `portsnap fetch` on this machine before.

I'll obviously provide any other details you need, but I don't have any idea of what details would be relevant.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use `su` instead of `sudo`?

Comment: What version of FreeBSD is it? If it is a version that is not supported anymore the ports are not available anymore after a while.

Comment: I don't remember, but it was almost certainly the most recent release at the time.

Answer (score -1):

Do you perhaps have a proxy configured in your environment variables? In that case use the -E flag to `sudo` that passes through the complete environment (which it does not do by default for security reasons):

```
sudo -E portsnap fetch
```

An alternative is to 'keep' HTTP_PROXY (or whatever the relevant variable is called). Edit `/usr/local/etc/sudoers` and add a line like the following:

```
Defaults env_keep += "HTTP_PROXY"
```

You can further limit the scope of this potential security hole via configuring things in more detail, see `sudoers(5)`.

Comment: Good thought, but nope, no proxy.

Comment: Ok, but did you try it? Does `portsnap fetch` without `sudo` work; as in, it fetches a file and *then* fails?

Comment: I tried `sudo -E portsnap fetch` and it didn't work. Without `sudo`, it just tells me I don't have write permissions for `/var/db/portsnap`. (Thanks for following up!)

Comment: Did you try to open up permissions to see whether portsnap does continue for a normal user?

Comment: You mean add write permissions for a normal user to `/var/db/portsnap`?